# how do i redirect the output of nosetests to a textfile?

Tags: python, nosetests

I've tried "nosetests p1.py > text.txt" and it is not working.

What is the proper way to pipe this console output?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
nosetests -s p1.py > text.txt 2>&1
```

Last --obvious--tip: If you are not in the test file directory, add before the .py file.

Comment: 2>&1 sends stderr to stdout and all of that will go to text.txt

Answer (score 2):

I want to add more detail here.

On my version (v1.3.7) Nose is logging on `stderr` instead of the expected `stdout`. Why nose logs on `stderr` instead of `stdout` is beyond me. So the solution is to redirect the `stderr` stream to your file. The redirect character sends `stdout` by default. The `--nocapture, -s` flag is used to stop nose from capturing your own `print` statements.

`$ nosetests -s -v test/ > stdout.log 2> stderr.log`

One thing to note, is although `stderr` seems to be flushed on each output, `stdout` does not get flushed, so if you are `tail`ing the `stdout.log` file, you will not see output until nose or the OS decides to flush. So if you think it's not working try exiting the test runner which will cause `stdout` to flush.

See this answer on redirecting [linux streams](https://askubuntu.com/a/625230/450512).

Answer (score 1):

parameter `-s` - Not capturing stdout

Comment: Ah, yes, if you want the stdout from your process, you do need to specify -s